# Customization of devloper portal to put api published time in overview of devprortal

Tags: reactjs, wso2-api-manager

This time should be shown in the developer portal overview.
Can it be done? if yes how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries you could use for example: moment js or date-fns

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow();     // 4 years ago
```

https://date-fns.org/

```
formatDistance(subDays(new Date(), 3), new Date(), { addSuffix: true })// "3 days ago"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a UI customization to achieve this. `createdTime` and `lastUpdatedTime` are returned in the Publisher REST API response when getting an API. You have to check whether those are returned in the Devportal REST API response for [getting an API](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#tag/APIs/paths/%7E1apis%7E1%7BapiId%7D/get). If those values are returned, you can use them directly to do the customization. Otherwise, it will not be possible.